# Access details of subfolders of folders in inbox in a shared mailbox

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Shared mailbox name: `trvx-prog.obs@orange.com`

I need:

- to access folders Madhvi and P_Wardah with their four sub folders
- set a date range for report extraction (with the subject, sender, date sent, folder name we are accessing)
- automate to run each week

I am not able to access the second folder and the subfolders

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub EmailStatsV3()
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim varOutput() As Variant
    Dim lngcount As Long
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ShareInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim SubFolder As Object

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("trvx-prog.obs@orange.com") '// Owner's Name or email address
    Set ShareInbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = ShareInbox.Folders("P_Wardah")
    
    ReDim varOutput(1 To SubFolder.Items.Count, 1 To 4)

    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
        If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
            lngcount = lngcount + 1
            varOutput(lngcount, 1) = Item.ReceivedTime 'stats on when received
            varOutput(lngcount, 2) = Item.Subject 'to split out prefix
            varOutput(lngcount, 3) = Item.Sender
            varOutput(lngcount, 4) = SubFolder.Name
        End If
    Next

    'Creates a blank workbook in excel
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlSht = xlApp.Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)

    xlSht.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(varOutput, 1), _
      UBound(varOutput, 2)).Value = varOutput
    xlApp.Visible = True
End Sub
```

- Received details of only folder P_Wardah
- Need to access the folder of Madhvi
- Need to access the sub folders of P_Wardah and Madhvi which are (Treated, No Perimeter, Follow Up, Pending)
- Need to classify them for a date range of each week

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer - Just an aid to help you move forward

You also need a loop to iterate through all the sub folders of SubFolder
Eg

```
For Each xFldr In SubFolder.Folders
   ' Recursive Call to process xFldr
Next
```

So your folder processing routine needs to be in a Sub of it's own and then call itself (recursive call)